# Capturar imagen con la Cámara y mostrarla en un ImageView

Tags: android

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de la documentación oficial:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPhotoView

He hecho todo igual pero, recibo el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.rrgt19.partyfinder/com.rrgt19.partyfinder.activity.AddActivity}: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4324)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

Permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

FileProvider:

```
<provider
           android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.rrgt19.partyfinder/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Código:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        // Views
        mPhotoImageView = findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);

        // Listeners
        mPhotoImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mPhotoImageView) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            225);
                }


                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            226);
                }
            } else {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); // Aquí es null
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Actualmente, logro tirar la foto correctamente pero, cuando hago click en OK, para pasar a mi Activity, el App se cierra. Estoy usando Android Nougat 7.0 en el emulador y en mi teléfono personal.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Esto sucede en emulador? que versión de sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Sucede en el emulador y en mi equipo personal, en ambos estoy usando Android Nougat 7.0

Comment: ya hiciste la prueba con un dispositivo físico?, los emuladores tienden a fallar, es mejor debuguear en un dispositivo físico

Comment: @CarlosQuintero He hecho pruebas en varios y sigo presentando el mismo error. Haciendo Debug encuentro que `Bundle extras` es `null` y no entiendo el por qué. Logro tomar la foto, cuando la acepto que entro a `onActivityResult`, mi variable `extras` es `null`. Alguna idea?.

Comment: @RobertGomez he revisado el problema, te sugiero revisar la aplicación de github, pero describo como solucionar el problema, de hecho a partir de Marshmallow me parece no es posible enviar los datos de la camara mediante un bundle, revisa mi respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeramente es importante comentar que tu aplicación debe usar los siguientes permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Es importante requerir los permisos manualmente si el dispositivo usa OS 6.0 o posterior, llama este método antes de usar la camara:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    225);
        }
    }if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted CAMERA.");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    226);
        }
    }

}
```

Con respecto a el error que comentas en tu pregunta:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

este se origina aquí:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
```

te recomiendo realices este método para obtener la Uri del archivo:

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            photoURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

y al tomar la foto realices este cambio en `onActivityResult()` , en donde recibirás la foto mediante [getContentResolver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()):

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); // Aquí es null
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }*/

        }
    }
```

de esta forma se abrira la camara sin problema :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y podrás agregar la imagen tomada por la cámara sin problema dentro de tu `ImageView` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este sería el código de tu clase completo:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0 /*1*/;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Uri photoURI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        // Views
        mPhotoImageView = findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);

        // Listeners
        mPhotoImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mPhotoImageView) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            225);
                }


                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            226);
                }
            } else {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                photoURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AddActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); // Aquí es null
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }*/

        }
    }

}
```

---

De hecho yo tuve el mismo problema que comentas, te recomiendo revises esta aplicación:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/TakePicture

Comment: Funciona. Una pregunta, cuál era el problema exactamente? Qué pasó con `data` en `onActivityResult`, por qué ya no obtenemos la foto con este? Lo más importante, ya no necesito usar `FileProvider` en mi `Manifest` y tampoco un `@xml/file_paths`? Si quieres puedes editar tu respuesta hablando un poco de esto para que futuros usuarios sepan qué se ha hecho y por qué.

Comment: En realidad al parecer no se permite desde Marshmallow el envio de la información de la foto, de hecho los datos enviados en el intent no son recibidos { }.

Comment: Y qué pasa con `FileProvider`, ya no lo necesito? Puedo eliminarlo de mi Manifest o se necesita para que todo funcione?

Comment: No es necesario el Fileprovider pero si los permisos Camera y WRITE_EXTERAL_STORAGE ya que estas accediendo a las imagenes mediante la clase MediaStore, de hecho puedes revisar la aplicación que tengo en Github.

Comment: Veo que la imagen se guarda en el equipo en una carpeta llamada Pictures. Esto se hace por defecto o dónde le has indicado que se guarde en una carpeta con ese nombre?

Comment: @RobertGomez esto se define aquí: getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

Comment: A lo que me refiero es, por qué en una carpeta llamada `Pictures`, se indica este folder de manera implícita? Si quisiera que la imagen se guardara en la carpeta `Camera`, sería otra solución diferente entonces? Otra cosa, por qué la imagen cuando la tomas, aparece en el ImageView y en `Gallery` volteada de cabeza?, alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: @RobertGomez en este caso debes cambiar a DIRECTORY_DCIM : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848645/how-to-get-the-default-directory-of-photo-made-by-camera-in-android

Comment: La solución que indicas es con `File` y en tu ejemplo de GitHub (lo he implementado en mi proyecto, es más fácil y corto) no usas `File` en ningún lado. Cómo podría hacerlo entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que guardar el file name cuando guardas la imagen.

```
URI imagenUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(<path to your file>));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imagenUri);
```

Comment: Hola amigo, he probado tu solución pero obtengo el error `..................../files/Pictures/JPEG_20180823_093811_3228858113393268186.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`.

Answer (score 0):

Para coger una fotográfia en un ImageView de la APP con poca calidad, a mí me ha servido con el siguiente código.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//Metodo que llama el botón para tomar la imagen. No es de calidad, es para usar como iconos y poco más.
public void tomarFotografia(View v) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");                                                                   
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.destinoFoto);  //"destinoFoto" es el imageView seleccionad en la APP para mostrar la fotografía tomada.
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es colocar esto asi

```
photoURI.toString()
```

convertir a String la `photoURI` en el `putextra`, asi no se te cierra la apk al tomar la foto.