# Error al abrir la cámara en app android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Tengo los permisos de la cámara en el manifest, pero al abrir la cámara desde el tlf físico y desde el emulador me arroja este error en la consola:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.sgm.fow.api_face, PID: 31628
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3
>   cmp=com.huawei.camera/.ThirdCamera clip={text/uri-list
>   U:file:///storage/07BD-1914/Android/data/com.sgm.fow.api_face/files/Pictures/IMG_3314201685479701346.jpg}
>   (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e81ea6a
>   31628:com.sgm.fow.api_face/u0a434} (pid=31628, uid=10434) with revoked
>   permission android.permission.CAMERA
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1946)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1892)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4373)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1631)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4751)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:744)
>           at com.sgm.fow.api_face.actividades.SelectImageActivity.takePhoto(SelectImageActivity.java:122)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: Mira a ver si es por hacerlo en el hilo principal del programa, igula lo tienes que hacer dentro de un asynktask

Comment: Mi pregunta es si haz verificado si tienes los permisos antes de realizar el intent, ya que desde Android 6 debes pedir permisos para pedir la camara aparte de lo que este declarado en el manifest.

Comment: El error a surgido a raíz de actualizar el gradle y subir el minSdkVersion, etc... Es posible que el error sea por los permisos?. Puedes mostrarme un ejemplo para los permisos de la cámara?

Comment: @LasPerseidas cuando actualizas targetSdkVersion a 23 o posterior, ahora para sistemas operativos 6.0 o posterior tienes que realizar la petición del permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE de forma manual, revisa elmétodo que agregué en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El stack trace indica que el problema es de permisos.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.huawei.camera/.ThirdCamera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/07BD-1914/Android/data/com.sgm.fow.api_face/files/Pictures/IMG_3314201685479701346.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e81ea6a 31628:com.sgm.fow.api_face/u0a434} (pid=31628, uid=10434) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Si subiste a una versión posterior a Android 6, tenés que, además de declarar los permisos en el manifest, pedir permisos en tiempo de ejecución. (Supongo que esto es a lo que se refería @Carlosgub.

La estrategia es, cuando inicia la app, verificar si la misma tiene todos los permisos que necesita. 
Si le falta alguno lo pide.
Y luego, cada vez, antes de ejecutar la funcionalidad que requiere el permiso, hay que verificar si **TODAVIA** se sigue contando con el permiso dado que el usuario puede revocarlo en cualquier momento. Entonces nuevamente se verifica si se cuenta con ese o esos permisos en particular.

Cuando se pide el permiso el usuario puede Aceptar, Declinar, o Declinar y que nunca más le pregunten.

Por eso antes de pedir el permiso hay que verificar si ya se cuenta con el mismo, y en caso de que no, si el usuario ya pidio que no le pregunten más. Si no quieren que le pregunten más hay que mostar algún mensaje diciendo que la funcionalidad necesita el permiso X y que debe habilitarlo desde el menú de configuración de Android. Y en la app simplemente hay que no ejecutar la funcionalidad.

Por otro lado si el permiso fue declinado una vez, y no se especificó que no se vuelva a preguntar, puede mostrarse una modal aclarando porque se necesita el permiso y luego volver a pedirlo dándole la oportunidad al usuario de acpetar.

La implementación es bastante compleja, y tal vez no está muy bien explicada en los dox de Android. Pero hay varios tutoriales de como hacerlo.

[Documentación de Android para pedir permisos en Android 6+](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 1):

El error indica que se genera al dar "clic" a un elemento:

> Could not execute method for android:onClick at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)

y posteriormente **se especifica que el método onClick realiza una petición de la cámara, pero tu aplicación no tiene los permisos requeridos**, en realidad este es el problema principal:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting
>   Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3
>   cmp=com.huawei.camera/.ThirdCamera clip={text/uri-list
>   U:file:///storage/07BD-1914/Android/data/com.sgm.fow.api_face/files/Pictures/IMG_3314201685479701346.jpg}
>   (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{e81ea6a
>   31628:com.sgm.fow.api_face/u0a434} (pid=31628, uid=10434) with revoked
>   permission android.permission.CAMERA at

Te sugiero mandes llamar dentro del método `onCreate()` el siguiente método

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
    checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Este sería el método que realiza la petición de los permisos requeridos para la cámara :

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    225);
        }
    }if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted CAMERA.");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    226);
        }
    }

}
```

En tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` te sugiero agregar lo siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Como ejemplo de como abrir la cámara, revisa esta respuesta:

[Capturar imagen con la Cámara y mostrarla en un ImageView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190805/capturar-imagen-con-la-c%C3%A1mara-y-mostrarla-en-un-imageview)

Comment: PERFECTO PROBLEMA RESUELTO, efectivamente era problema de los permisos. Tenía que pedirlos en tiempo de ejecución, cosa que no estaba haciendo, cosa necesaria a partir de Android 6.0. Gracias a todos por este empujoncito.

Comment: Como actualizaste a targetSdkVersion a 23  se tiene que pedir permisos, pero en realidad esto es lo que se tiene que hacer ya que nuestro targetSdkVersion  tiene que ir aumentando conforme pasa el tiempo,saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Has probado colocando los permisos en el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Si tengo ambos permisos.