# ¿Como tomar una foto y almacenar en android?

Tags: java, android

al ejecutar la funcion para tomar la foto la aplicacion se detiene y en el Logcat me muestra esto

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
>           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
>           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
>           at com.example.miagenda.CrearEventoActivity.tomarfoto(CrearEventoActivity.java:247)

Siendo la linea de CrearEventoActivity.java:247 :

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
```

Función para tomar la foto

```
public void tomarfoto(View view) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Función en onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error exactamente se produce? Para poder ayudarte mejor pon el error en tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. Ya edite el error.

Comment: Existe una pregunta similar en el sitio, se toma la imagen y se guarda en disco, la puedes revisar aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190805/capturar-imagen-con-la-c%c3%a1mara-y-mostrarla-en-un-imageview , el problema se origina en :  Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);    Si tienes una duda puedes comentar para apoyarte, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No parece un error convencional, al menos no tiene pinta de ser un problema conciso. Pero intentaré darte la mejor respuesta posible.

Primero que nada en tu archivo ***Manifest.xml*** debes declarar que tu aplicación necesita de un **FileProvider** y declarando la autoridad (vienen siendo algo así como el solicitante, para el sistema tener una idea de que app solicita archivos) de tu aplicación con la palabra ".provaider"

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
</provider>
```

Ahora cuando intentas obtener el Uri de tu photo. Tienes que pasarle la autoridad como la declaraste en tu provaider en **Manifest.xml**. Puedes usar varias maneras de hacerlo:

- Pasando el id de tu aplicacion y añadiendo **.provaider** al final:

FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.example.android.miapliacion.provider"), foto);

- Una manera más dinámica es utilizar la clase **BuildConfig** que tiene el id de tu aplicación y añadir **.provaider**:

  FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), foto);