# Crash al intentar tomar una foto (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando tomar una foto , que le agrege un nombre y que la guarde, el problema es que al momento de hacerlo(pude descubrir que el problema me lo da en una linea en particular) , esto me genera un Crash, hasta el punto que se me cierra la app en el cel.

este es el provider:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Este es mi Resource (file_paths)

```
<external-path
  name="Proyecto3"
  path="Android/data/com.example.proyecto3/files/Pictures/"/>
```

Método para tomar foto y crear el archivo

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
public void tomarFoto(View view) {
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
  if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
    photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    // Error occurred while creating the File
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {

//EN LA SIGUIENTE LINEA DONDE PUDE DESCRUBIR (GRACIAS A LOS LOG) QUE ME CAUSA EL CRASH//
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.proyecto3", photoFile);

        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
      }
   }
 }
```

Tambien vi en otras preguntas que hicieron ,que recomendaban sustituir por esta linea pero el tema aqui que esta linea a mi me da un error "Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'" al punto de ni poder compilar

```
 Uri photoURI =FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), photoFile);
```

Si alguien sabe que puede ser , se lo agradeceria mucho, llevo varios dias con este problema, cualquier duda pregunten

Comment: Ayudaría si dejaras el error que obtienes. Puedes obtenerlo con logcat.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? es importante revisar el LogCat

Comment: Te sugiero revisar esta respuesta, [Capturar imagen con la Cámara y mostrarla en un ImageView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190805/capturar-imagen-con-la-c%c3%a1mara-y-mostrarla-en-un-imageview) tal vez tu pregunta ya esta respondida, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Hola prueba creando tu uri asi:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, NombreDeTuClase.this.getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
```

igual seria bueno que mencionaras el error que te esta mandando
Saludos.

Comment: Esto es lo que está realizando el usuario.

Comment: revisa bien antes de estar fastidiando, no es lo mismo

Comment: Revisa por favor la pregunta, es esto lo que realiza el usuario: Uri photoURI =FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), photoFile);

Comment: si sabes leer? Tambien vi en otras preguntas que hicieron ,que recomendaban sustituir por esta linea pero el tema aqui que esta linea a mi me da un error "Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'" al punto de ni poder compilar

Comment: A ti te da un error porque seguramente no tienes definido el valor en local.properties, la clase BuildConfig genera variables con base en lo que se define en este archivo, lo mejor es preguntar al OP antes de responder, por ejemplo pedir especifique que error obtiene.

Comment: eso respóndele a el, a mi déjame en paz, no tienes otra cosa mejor que hacer? lee bien la publicación, y responde, deja de meterte en las respuestas de los demás

Comment: @DavidEstrada Bienvenido, muchas gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero revisar nuestro [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), aquí nadie está fastidiando ni molestando, solamente se le está indicando que la respuesta no es lo suficiente correcta para la pregunta del OP, de la cual vendría mejor esperar a que el OP brinde más detalles y así tu respuesta podría mejorarse. Ten el cordial respeto y moderación con los demás, un saludo.

Comment: Si decís que no es lo mismo @DavidEstrada, entonces editá tu respuesta para describir qué de diferente tiene el código con lo que muestra el OP :) Por cierto, es innecesario tratar de menos a los demás: todos quienes moderamos el sitio procuramos que el contenido en [es.so] sea de calidad, por lo tanto siempre que sea necesario dejaremos comentarios para mejorar las preguntas o las respuestas. _No es molestar._ Lee [answer].

Comment: si lose, una disculpa, pero todo el día de ayer este "moderador" se la paso tratando de invalidar mis respuestas y restándome puntos sin razones aparentes. Y Sobre la pregunta no es lo mismo, en caso de no tener configurado en local.properties, la clase BuildConfig, de la forma en que indico le funcionaria